# Comparison between Bayes estimators

Tags: self-study, bayesian, estimation, hierarchical-bayesian, loss-functions

> 1. Consider the quadratic loss $L(\theta,\delta)=(\theta-\delta)^2$, with
>      prior given $\pi(\theta)$ where $\pi(\theta)\sim U(0,1/2)$.  Let
>      $f(x|\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(x), \theta>0$ the
>      likelihood. Find the Bayes estimator $\delta^\pi$.
> 2. Consider the weighted quadratic loss
>      $L_w(\theta,\delta)=w(\theta)(\theta-\delta)^2$ where
>      $w(\theta)=\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,1/2)}$ with prior
>      $\pi_1(\theta)=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(\theta)$. Let $f(x|\theta)=\theta
>     x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(x), \theta>0$ be the likelihood.  Find the
>      Bayes estimator $\delta^\pi_1$.
> 3. Compare $\delta^\pi$ and $\delta^\pi_1$

First I noticed that $f(x|\theta)\sim Beta(\theta,1)$, and I assumed that that is the likelihood, otherwise I don't get any posterior, then
$$\pi(\theta|x)\propto f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}*2\mathbb{I}_{(0,1/2)}(\theta)\sim Beta(\theta,1)$$
so the Bayes estimator with respect to quadratic loss is
$$\mathbb{E}[\pi(\theta|x)]=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$$

I'm looking in the book **The Bayesian Choice** and there is a theorem about the Bayes estimator associated with weighted quadratic loss and it is given by
$$\delta^\pi(x)=\frac{\mathbb{E}^\pi[w(\theta)\theta|x]}{\mathbb{E}^\pi[w(\theta)|x]}$$

Can someone explain to me how I calculate it?

What I tried is:

$$\delta^\pi(x)=\frac{\frac{\int \theta w(\theta)f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta}{\int w(\theta)f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta}}{\frac{\int f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta}{\int w(\theta)f(x\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta}}$$

I know that the support is $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, but when I tried to integrate in the numerator

$$\int \theta w(\theta)f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\theta\theta x^{\theta-1}d\theta=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\theta^2 x^\theta d\theta$$

I get no good results.

Comment: Isn't $w(\theta)$ nonnegative here?

Comment: I don't understand your remark about "just for $w(\theta)$ nonnegative," because (1) a loss function won't ever become negative and (2) your loss function cannot be negative anyway.

Comment: @whuber Gosh, now I realized my idiocy, I was looking at the indicator support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that I corrected the original wording of the question wrt the indicator functions in your likelihood definitions as they have to be functions of $x$ not $\theta$. Hence the likelihood is $$f(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(x)$$ that clearly integrates to one: $$\int_0^1 \theta x^{\theta-1}\text{d}x = 1$$

Second, the posterior in $\theta$ is not a Beta function since as indicated by [Greenparker](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/31978/greenparker)
$$\pi(\theta|x)\propto\, \mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2]}(\theta)\theta x^{\theta-1}\propto
\mathbb{I}_{[0,1/2]}(\theta)\,\theta \exp\{\log(x)\theta\}$$
Due to the constraint on the values of $\theta$ it is not a Gamma distribution either, but a truncation of the Gamma distribution.

Hence the Bayes estimator is the posterior expectation 
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[\theta|x] &= \int_0^{1/2} \theta\times\theta \exp\{\log(x)\theta\}\text{d}\theta \Big/ \int_0^{1/2} \theta \exp\{\log(x)\theta\}\text{d}\theta\\&= \int_0^{1/2} \theta^2 \exp\{\log(x)\theta\}\text{d}\theta \Big/ \int_0^{1/2} \theta \exp\{\log(x)\theta\}\text{d}\theta\\\end{align*}
$$
that may seem to require the use of the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) but which can be derived in closed form by integration by part:
$$\int_0^{1/2} \theta^k \exp\{-\alpha\theta\}\text{d}\theta =
\frac{-1}{\alpha}\left[\theta^k \exp\{-\alpha\theta\}\right]_0^{1/2} +
\frac{k}{\alpha}\int_0^{1/2} \theta^{k-1} \exp\{-\alpha\theta\}\text{d}\theta$$ since
$$\int_0^{1/2} \exp\{-\alpha\theta\}\text{d}\theta = \frac{1-\exp\{-\alpha/2\}}{\alpha}$$

Last, as indicated in [my book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983), indeed, minimising in $\delta$
$$\int w(\theta)(\theta-\delta)^2 \pi(\theta|x) \text{d}\theta$$
is equivalent to minimising in $\delta$
$$\int w(\theta)(\theta-\delta)^2 \pi(\theta)f(x|\theta) \text{d}\theta$$ which itself is equivalent to minimising in $\delta$
$$\int (\theta-\delta)^2 w(\theta)\pi(\theta)f(x|\theta) \text{d}\theta$$ which amounts to replacing the original prior $\pi$ with a new prior $w(\theta)\pi(\theta)$ that needs to be renormalised into a density, that is,
$$\pi_1(\theta)=w(\theta)\pi(\theta) \Big/\int w(\theta)\pi(\theta)\text{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 6):

Your answer for the squared error loss part is wrong.

$$\pi(\theta|x) \propto f(x|\theta) \pi(\theta) = 2\theta x^{\theta-1}I_{(0,1/2)}(\theta). $$

This is a $Beta(\theta,1)$ distribution in $x$, *not* in $\theta$, and the random variable in the posterior is $\theta$. So your answer is incorrect, and the correct answer would be the posterior mean of that distribution.

For the second part,

(The prior for the weighted loss function is $\pi_1$ but you refer to it as $\pi$. I am switching notation back to $\pi_1$.)

Let $\pi'(\theta) = cw(\theta) \pi_1(\theta)$, where $c$ is a normalizing constant. You need to calculate

\begin{align*}
\delta^{\pi_1}(x) & = \dfrac{E^{\pi_1}[w(\theta) \theta |x ]}{E^{\pi_1}[w(\theta|x)]}\\
& = \dfrac{\int w(\theta) \theta f(x|\theta) \pi_1(\theta)\, d\theta}{\int w(\theta) f(x|\theta)\pi_1(\theta)\, d\theta}\\
& = \dfrac{\int \theta f(x|\theta) \pi'(\theta) \,d\theta}{\int f(x|\theta) \pi'(\theta) \, d\theta}\\
& = E^{\pi'}[\theta|x]
\end{align*}

Thus, for weighted least squares loss function, the theorem says that the Bayes estimate is the posterior mean with respect to a different prior. The prior being
$$\pi'(\theta) \propto w(\theta) \pi_1(\theta). $$

The normalizing constant is $ \int_{\theta} w(\theta) \pi(\theta) d\theta = E_{\pi_1}[w(\theta)]$.

\begin{align*}
E_{\pi_1}[w(\theta)] & = \int_{0}^{1/2} I_{0,1}(\theta) d(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

So the prior is $\pi'(\theta) = 2I_{(0,1/2)}(\theta)$. This is the same prior you had in the first question.

Thus the answer for the scenarios (whatever it is) will be the same. You can find the integral [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x+t%5E%7Bx-1%7D+from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+1%2F2). Although, it might be sufficient to right the form of the answer, and not complete the integral.